# Cassandra default_time_to_live and gc_grace_seconds property is not deleting data from the table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I set default_time_to_live 1 minute for a table and there is no counter field, still, the data is not cleared from the table. It's a 6 node cluster.

````
CREATE TABLE <DB>.<TABLE> (
unqid text PRIMARY KEY,
lastupdtdtm timestamp,
rltdid text,
tmtolive varint) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 10
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';```
````

Answer (score 0):

Setting a default TTL on a table will only apply to newly inserted data. SSTables are immutable in Cassandra -- they don't get updated/modified once they've been written to disk. This means that any existing data on disk will not have the new TTL applied to them so they won't automatically expire.

You will need to write an app preferably in Spark that would iterate over the partitions and either (a) update each partition with a TTL, or (b) delete the full partition. Otherwise, they won't expire on their own nor would they be deleted. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean the newly inserted data is only not removed from the table. 

1. Table created with "default_time_to_live" = 10
2. New data inserted

Even I alter the table by adding gc_grace_seconds =20, It still didnt removed the data.

Comment: Expired data don't get removed until the next compaction cycle. But they won't get returned during reads. Cheers!